# When is "me encanta" romantic?

Tags: verbos, connotaciones

I have heard that *me gusta* usually has a romantic connotation when referring to people (as opposed to just saying that you get along well with someone). What about *me encanta*? Does it always have romantic undertones or can it be used non-romantically to refer to a close friend or someone you deeply respect?

Comment: I don't want to seem vulgar but once I was having sex with a Colombian girl and during the act I said "me gusta" and she replied "me encanta". Later on she explained that "me encanta" is a expression used as a reply to "me gusta" during sexual intercorses

Comment: That's true, but not only during sexual intercorses :) In this context "me encanta" means "me gusta mucho". -¿Te gusta? - Me encanta.

Comment: It has to do with the context, the situation in which the expression is said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I would not use *me encanta* to refer to somebody I **just** respect (however deeply). I would use it, however, to refer to somebody I admire very much or something that I like very much:

> Me encanta el trabajo de Bertrand Russell, creo que sus ideas son geniales.
>
> Me encanta Cervantes, pues El Quijote es una maravilla.
>
> Me encanta el cine, veo muchas películas.

Generally speaking, if you are *encantado* by somebody, it means that you *admire* that person in the sense that you like them very much, not necessarily in a romantic fashion. You might have the deepest respect for a person like Ghandi, because you admire his passion, but if you don't agree with his ideas, you'd probably never say that you are *encantado* by him.

In other words, you may respect somebody very much without considering them role models, but if you are *encantado* by somebody, that person is likely to play some kind of model for you: it is somebody whose example you'd follow.

The romantic point of view is also correct, but mostly in a context of two people who are very close and probably sharing an intimate moment (not necessarily sexual):

> *¡Me encantas!*
>
> *Me encantan tus caricias*

A girl might say to her boyfriend *me encantas* in public (or a guy to a girl, or other combinations), perhaps in front of a group of close friend or relatives. For example, after receiving a birthday present during a family reunion, something like "¡Gracias! Me encanta el regalo y me encantas tú" sounds natural and would not make other people feel uncomfortable. However, saying *me encantan tus caricias* in front your partner's parents would probably end up being an awkward moment.

I hope that answers your question!

Answer (score 4):

Contrary to Janoma, I've used the expression *me encanta* many times to refer to some girl I liked a lot, usually in confidence to some friend, as in `Esa mina me encanta`. *Mina* is slang for girl/woman in Argentina. *Me gusta* would also be ok, but with a lot less intensity, to the point that *Esa mina me gusta* would not make much sense. `Esa mina me encanta` is very similar to saying `esa mina me mata`, but *me mata* has a more physical connotation than *me encanta*. Alguien puede encantarte por su forma de ser, pero el físico de otra puede ser matador (de ahí que te mata). `Esa mina me vuelve loco` is another way of saying the same thing, that can mean slightly different things depending on the situation. She can *volverte loco* for her personality, for her body, or some combination of factors.